# How to find the parent of a class file

Tags: document-classes, acm, lyx-layouts

I am trying to use the [ACM Small class](http://www.sigecom.org/ec15/ec-acmsmall.zip) in LyX. A [LyX Wiki page](http://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/CreatingLayouts) says to create a LyX layout based on the parent of the class file: "Lets assume, the LaTeX class amcsiggraph.cls is a descendant of article.cls, then the lyx layout to use is article.layout".

I looked at the ACM-Small class file, and haven't found any clue about whether it's a descendant of "article.cls" or of something else.

How can I find the parent of this class file?

Comment: From a quick view of `ec-acmsmall.cls`, no dependent class is loaded (it's not required), so it has no parent.

Comment: OK, so what layout should I use as the basis for the new layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be able to spot a parent class by looking for `\LoadClass` or `\LoadClassWithOptions` within the `.cls`. If none such entries exist, the most likely has no parent and was written from scratch. From a quick view of `ec-acmsmall.cls`, no dependent class is loaded (it's not required), so it has no parent.

In such cases, let's look at how the basic classes in LyX are constructed. Upon viewing `article.layout`, you'll note that it does

```
Input stdclass.inc
```

which `input`s some `st`an`d`ard `class`-related `inc`lusion file. In `stdclass.inc` you'll see

```
#Input stdcharstyles.inc
#Input stdcustom.inc
Input stdfloats.inc
Input stdcounters.inc
Input stdinsets.inc
Input stdlists.inc
Input stdsections.inc
Input stdstarsections.inc
Input stdtitle.inc
Input stdstruct.inc
Input lyxmacros.inc
Input stdlayouts.inc
Input stdciteformats.inc
```

which includes a whole host of component files, each of which are responsible for setting up a particular element of the bigger layout.

The approach would then be to use this as foundation and build the `.layout` from there. Given that `article.layout` itself is actually quite small, you fundamentally have to do this anyway for creating most of your own layouts.

After-thought: I've found the LyX documentation/help on layout creation to be somewhat lacking. There's no clear guidance as to how certain (La)TeX commands translate into the LyX environments. You almost always have to take some existing construction and modify it, rather than creating something from basic principles yourself.